# Context load from an APK file in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, load, apk, android-context

I am building a component-based application for Android. In short, I would like to load an APK file during runtime and execute code from it.

I used `DexClassLoader` with success to load and instantiate some classes, the problem lies in reading the APK's resources.

I would like to create a custom `Context` object that I could use to load these resources (with a `LayoutInflater` instance for example), similarly to the `createPackageContext()`, which does not work for my application since it is only looking into the installed packages.

Comment: This is something you may try (I didn`t tried myself, but that was what I thought when I searched the docs): `PackageManager.getPackageArchiveInfo` will return a `PackageInfo` which will allow you to get a `ApplicationInfo`. With that object you can call `PackageManager. getResourcesForApplication` to return you a `Resources` object.

Answer (score 1):

```
            InputStream in = getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.raw.fileName);
```

then just read from this stream. This example would open res/raw/fileName.html for reading. I however do not understand why to load classes for execution from your own apk file in such a problematic way. If I misunderstand and you need to load from some other apk file, then - who prevents from opening that file for the input and reading from it? It is just a compresses ZIP archive. I think you could construct your implementation overriding the data access methods and your instance could contain the reference to the file from where to read the data.